# Can I use RMAN to backup and restore data in a certain point in time?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, rman

I have an Oracle database over which I have full control. What I am doing is performing load testing on our application, which uses Oracle as a database. To do this, I initially set the database up with some dummy data. I'm calling this "Point A".

The load testing will consume this data, and I will have to restore the data so it looks exactly like it was in Point A before I can re-run them. The hard way to do this is using Data Pump, which takes a long time and seeing how I need to backup several schemas it's rather complex.

I was wondering if it was possible just to issue a `BACKUP DATABASE` on RMAN after I have the data set up. Then I would run my tests, and restore it using something like `RESTORE DATABASE FROM TAG <somedate>`, and that would be all I need to get my tests going again. There should be no changes to the control file or anything like that.

Is this a safe way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature specifically for that:

```
 CREATE RESTORE POINT before_test1 GUARANTEE FLASHBACK DATABASE;
 select NAME,SCN,TIME from v$restore_point; 
 exec perform_my_test1;
 SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
 STARTUP MOUNT;
 FLASHBACK DATABASE TO RESTORE POINT before_test1;
 DROP RESTORE POINT before_test1 ;
```

This is a database's feature, not RMAN's (commands are for sqlplus), see [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/flashdb.htm#BRADV71000) for the full setup and disclaimers.

To more precisely answer your question, RMAN can *also* be used for the task. The general script is:

```
run { 
  set until scn 123123123 ;
  restore database /* from tag ... */;
  recover database;
}
```

Don't use bare `RESTORE DATABASE FROM TAG` because without SET UNTIL it doesn't work as you'd expect in some scenarios.

I wouldn't say any of these two solutions are inherently safe, both have as many pitfalls as any other Oracle's advanced features, so you need to do some research upfront.

Comment: There's a command `exec perform_my_test1;` - where did `perform_my_test1` get defined?

Comment: Just usual Oracle disclaimer - Flashback database is Enterprise Edition feature.

Comment: @Confluence you state in your question that you want to perform some testing before restoring - he's just added that as a placeholder for your testing.

Comment: Real Application Test anyone?

Comment: Today I learned `OPEN DATABASE RESETLOGS` is a dangerous operation. I had this stuff in ASM and reorganized (deleted and recreated) some datafiles, and the end result was a major mess. I will try the `FLASHBACK` operation soon.

Comment: According to the documentation, FLASHBACK can have a significant performance overhead and cause disk space pressure. Unfortunately this would skew the performance numbers I am trying to get, making this option much less viable.